# Using ApplicationDbContext with DI from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to abstract any connection information away from my ApplicationDbContext class so that I can take advantage of different databases for development, staging, production. I start by registering a service from Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

My ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
     : base(options)
   {
   }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
         base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

When running this application I get the following error:

**InvalidOperationException**: Could not create an instance of type 'SquadApps.Data.ApplicationDbContext'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor.

So naturally I tried adding a parameterless constructor

```
public ApplicationDbContext() { }
```

Now getting another error:

**InvalidOperationException**: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

If I go back to having a connection string stored in the ApplicationDbContext class like so:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("........");
}
```

Then everything works fine but obviously this is not ideal and probably a bad practice. I think there is something i'm missing about the DI process and any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you registered your Identity as dependency in startup? services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: Yes exactly as written. This is registered straight after services.AddDbContext

Comment: I created a new WebApplication with individual user accounts using template. It created same code as yours but still works. Can you provide code which actually demonstrate the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be how I was trying to call the DI. I had incorrectly assumed DI would be able to be called per each IActionResult inside my controllers but in fact it must occur within the **constructor** of the controller. This makes the DI available to all IActionResult methods within the controller.

Example of the working DI call:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _ctx;
    private readonly CompanySettings _companySettings;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext ctx, IOptions<CompanySettings> settings)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _companySettings = settings.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new HomeViewModel();

        // _ctx and _companySettings can be used here

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: totally saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you _can_ use DI from the action-method. What you didn't realize you needed to do differently for that situation was to decorate each "DI" parameter with the `FromServices` attribute. 

E.g. This will work: `public IActionResult Index([FromServices] ApplicationDbContext ctx, [FromServices] IOptions<CompanySettings> settings)`. But this would result in the exception you saw: `public IActionResult Index(ApplicationDbContext ctx, IOptions<CompanySettings> settings)`